# Postgresql Count in multiple column

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to retrieve count(*) function with multiple rows. I am using the following query

```
select distinct agent, count(customer) as total_customer, 
(select count(january_1) from salestable where january_1!=0 group by agent) as sales_customer
from salestable 
where customer_type = "urban"
group by agent 
order by agent asc
```

At first I have retrieve distinct agent number then count how much customer he have. Note that there are few agent who have no customer. total distinct agent is 2000. But in count it retrieve 1600 as 400 agent has no customer. In another column named january_1 I have sales value. I want to get a table where 3 column will be listed with distinct agent, total no of customer and total no of sales. In january_1 column 0 means no sales. It should look like

```
| Agent | Customer | Service | Served
| Lynda | 6 | 4 | 0
| Marks  | 7 | 5 | 6
| Tomas | 6 | 3 | 2
```

But in result I am getting the following error

```
more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

What I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but think this is what you want

```
select agent, 
       count(customer) as total_customer, 
       count(case when january_1 <> 0 then 1 end)  as sales_customer
from salestable 
where customer_type = 'urban'
group by agent 
order by agent asc;
```

Alternatively this can be written with a `filter()` condition:

```
select agent, 
       count(customer) as total_customer, 
       count(*) filter where (january_1 <> 0)  as sales_customer
from salestable 
where customer_type = 'urban'
group by agent 
order by agent asc;
```

Comment: Can you help me little more? If I want to retrieve percentage of sales_customer in respect with total_customer in another column what should I do?